# How to display data which contains topics and sub topics like a book in an android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi I am building an android app which contains information regarding some 11 steps of a process. The 11 steps are displayed in a recyclerview in a activity. When you click on any topic its brief introducton appears in a separate activity. When you click on the details button one more activity appears with the full details regarding the step. Note the details contain Headings, sub headings, images and descriptions like in a book. I want to load the data dynamically in the same activity for every step instead of making 11 separate description activities. How do I acheive that.Add snapshot of what I am trying to acheive.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening activity from details button you can use expandable list view .

Comment: I wanna know about the data handling part. How do i load different data everytime in the same activity which shows details about the different topics

Comment: In which format you want to show details about different topics means list view,grid view etc

Comment: In the form of cards actually. I have added the screenshots of wat i want to do. I have already added all the layouts. I am confused as to how to display this data dynamically